# MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner failed to connect to database MySQL

Tags: mysql, msbuild, sonarqube

I am trying to analyze using MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.
Followed the steps mentioned here http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin

I am using Database - MySQL Server 5.6 and
Operating System - Windows

SonarQube.Analysis.xml

```
 <Property Name="sonar.host.url">http://ipaddress:9000</Property>  
 <Property Name="sonar.login">sonaruser</Property>
 <Property Name="sonar.password">userpassword</Property>
 <Property Name="sonar.jdbc.url">jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance</Property>
 <Property Name="sonar.jdbc.username">sonardbuser</Property>
 <Property Name="sonar.jdbc.password">sonardbuserpasswd</Property>
```

Last step - MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end

```
....
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.5.6
09:22:51.341 INFO  - Load global referentials...
09:22:52.268 INFO  - Load global referentials done: 929 ms
09:22:52.285 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\abcd\.sonar\cache
09:22:52.293 INFO  - Install plugins
09:22:53.255 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
09:22:53.285 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/sonar
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 5.864s
Final Memory: 3M/15M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to connect to database
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Please help, What I am missing?

Comment: Make sure that the settings file used by the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner `begin` and `end` phases are actually the same. During the `end` invocation, the sonar-runner that is being launched tries to connect to the default database, as you can see from the log line: `09:22:53.285 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/sonar`

Comment: It is the same file, I have added the path of MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner in ENV Variable "PATH", and opened the VS Command prompt and working from project sln directory path.